# How to catch data from SIM

Tags: command, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, sim-card

I use a CardReader to communicate to a SIM-card.
For example, I need to get an IMSI from the SIM card.
To do this I send some commands    (`SELECT 3F00/7F20/6F07`):

```
A0 A4 00 00 02 3F 00  
A0 A4 00 00 02 7F 20 
A0 A4 00 00 02 6F 07
```

and here I send `READ BINARY` command

`A0 B0 00 00 09`

and after that I receive `90 00 --> Ok` - normal ending of the command.
Hey! And where is my IMSI stored?? How can I catch data, which were read by "`A0 B0 00 00 09`" command?
If I try "`A0 C0 00 00 00`" command (`GET RESPONSE`) I will get an Error.

[image: All the commands - step by step]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send Get Response Command "`A0 C0 00 00 00`" after Read Data.
There are 9 bytes of data in reply to your Read Data Command "`A0 B0 00 00 09`".

Comment: Ok, but how can I get these 9 bytes? Which next command should I put to catch the answer?

Comment: It is in your reply data to the Read Data command. See rightmost column. You ask to read 9 Bytes - you should get 9 bytes of data and status bytes "90 00".

Comment: To clarify this: One should send Get Response only, if 61 xx was given as response (with LE=xx). This will typically be the case for a card communicating via T=0 protocol.